# Using const for requiring a module

Tags: javascript, node.js

In one of my NodeJS application , I noticed the below code;

```
const { Function } = require('./modules/helpers.js')
```

Is this valid? Also any benefits of using const for the require ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `destructuring assignment` is a valid syntax:

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

```
({a, b} = {a: 10, b: 20});
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

EDIT:

As for the benefits, It is a syntax sugar in most of the case. It allows you to refer the import functions directly as `Function` instead of `Helper.Function`.

It can also [reduce your bundle.js file size](https://lacke.mn/reduce-your-bundle-js-file-size/).

Comment: Also any significance of using the "const" here ?

Comment: scroll down the articel in the link to look for that answer....it's yes.

Comment: It is a new feature of ES6. As of ES6, it is preferred to use `const` for `require`s, so that the imported functions cannot be changed. However, `const` does not make an object immutable.

Answer (score -1):

Making use of `const` has some **big improvements** for yourself. So you can't change your imported modules anymore. This imported modules is so called <s>immutable</s>, which is really good for some points. For more have a look over here: [Short Introduction into immutable data structures](http://jlongster.com/Using-Immutable-Data-Structures-in-JavaScript)

**Edit**: `const` doesn't really mean that a value isn't changeable anymore, but it means that the object at this point can't be reassigned. *(Thanks to @Mark Stosberg for pointing that out again)*

*(simply the code is more easily to reason about and it is about good code style)*

And the **syntax is valid ES6 destructing syntax**. Make sure that your module exports an variable called `Function`. For more have a look over here: [MDN Destruction Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: The imported modules remain mutable. From the [official docs for const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const): *The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.*